# Create composite spectrum from two unnormalized spectra

Tags: python, scipy

In Python, I'm trying to normalize two arrays and then take the average of the region where they overlap to create a new composite array.

To do this, I figure I have to:

1. find the region of overlap,
2. interpolate the overlapped y values,
3. iterate through to find the normalization constant of the best fit, and then
4. paste the pieces together to form my new curve

With some semi-random values, here's what that looks like:

[image]

This code works great for small data sets whose y values aren't too far apart, but Python crashes when there are orders of magnitude between Y1 and Y2 (obviously due to the iteration). Here's the code:

```
X1o = [x for x in X1 if x > X2[0]]
X2o = [x for x in X2 if x < X1[-1]]
Y1o = [y for y in Y1[(len(Y1)-len(X1o)):]]
Y2o = [y for y in Y2[:len(X2o)]]
Y2o = list(interp(X1o,X2o,Y2o))

c = abs(min(Y1o)-max(Y2o))
Y2test = [y2+c for y2 in Y2o]
Y2s = []
d = 0.01*min(Y2test)
while min(Y2test) < max(Y1o):
  Y2test = [y+d for y in Y2test]
  Y2s.append(Y2test)
  plot(X1o,Y2test,c='k',alpha=0.5)

idx = min(map(lambda i: (u.squaredError(Y1o, i), i, Y2s.index(i)), Y2s))[-1]         
Yavg = [(y1+y2)/2 for y1,y2 in zip(Y1o,Y2s[idx])]
diff = Y2s[idx][0]-Y2o[0]

X = [x for x in X1 if x < X2[0]] + X1o + [x for x in X2 if x > X1[-1]]
Y = [y for x,y in zip(X1,Y1) if x < X2[0]] + Yavg + [y+diff for x,y in zip(X2,Y2) if x > X1[-1]]
```

I really need to do this with stellar spectra with thousands of data points and up to 20 orders of magnitude in spread between the y values.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"obviously due to the iteration"* What makes you say this?

Comment: If you want a more efficient code, you can start by getting rid of the list comprehensions and use numpy array operations.

Comment: @tiago I've just started to take a look at Numpy. Any in particular you think might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would benefit greatly from numpy and using less python lists, which are inefficient, in particular your line `Y2s.append(Y2test)`. When your `while` cycle is too long, you're just going to be appending to a very long list, which is slow and inefficient.

That being said, the bottleneck of your code is the minimisation. You're currently doing it brute force with python lists. You'd greatly benefit from using one of [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) functions.

Here are some broad suggestions of what I'd do:

1. Find x coordinate extremes for both spectra, interpolate both to grid of common x values.
2. Use a flavour of scipy.optimize.fmin to do the minimisation for you and calculate the best normalisation.
3. Interpolate parts of the normalised spectra to a common grid

Here's some sample code (non-tested) with fmin:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

# y1 = interpolated values for one of the spectra
# y2 = interpolated values for the other spectra, normalise this one 

def errfunc(p, a1, a2):
    return np.sum(a1 - a2 * p)

p0 = 1.  # initial guess
norm_factor = opt.fmin(errfunc, p0, args=(y1, y2))
```

And this should give you the best fitting `norm_factor`.

Comment: Yes! This works great, though I changed `errfunc()` to `np.sum(abs(a1 - (a2 + p)))` to find the normalization offset of the best fit instead of the normalization factor. Thanks so much!